# MFC: Copy/Paste from toolbar when using EditLabel in a CListView/CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistview

I have a `CFormView` with a `CListView`, when using `CListView::EditLabel()` you can right click and paste, or highlight and copy.  However the toolbar has copy/paste disabled.   What is the appropriate way to handle that and have the copy/paste work via the toolbar ?

I know I can use `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` to get the enabled, but when enabled they don't copy/paste when editing a label on the `CListView`.

Thanks.

Comment: I imagine you would have to handle the toolbar messages, and implement the functionality yourself. Might be somewhat involved since clicking outside the (temporary) edit control created for label editing will usually end the label editing process. I don't know whether implementing something like [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160912-00/?p=94295) on a toolbar control allows toolbar buttons to be clicked while keeping input focus on the label edit control.

Comment: I don't think setting the `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler would block normal or default operation. Setting the `ON_COMMAND` handler will affect it though (calling the new function). Pls note that `Ctrl+C/V` are the default shortcuts for copy/paste, however they are typically defined in the keyboard accelerator for a MFC app. I would say, create a new MFC project, using the `CEditView` class also using a Toolbar like yours (will create a Notepad-like app without writing a single line of code!). It will also contain the Copy/Paste toolbar buttons, so you can examine the code (incl MFC sources).

Comment: If I am correct, any menu (and thus toolbar) item that does not have a menu handler, will show disabled.

Comment: The edit label stays when clicking on the toolbar - The list control doesn't have a paste operation like an edit control.  So I guess to make it happen I would need to get access to the edit control the edit label is using.